# Strange behaviour of javascript while chaining math comparison operators

Tags: javascript

When checking in chrome console running following statements return strange results.

0.5 < 0.6 < 0.7    => returns false

1.5 < 1.6 < 1.7    => return true

Can anyone explain this behaviour?

```js
alert("0.5 < 0.6 < 0.7  = " + (0.5 < 0.6 < 0.7));
alert("1.5 < 1.6 < 1.7  = " + (1.5 < 1.6 < 1.7));
```

Comment: I don't like these questions. There's already a million of them, someone meddling in a console and then being surprised. There's an infinity of possible combinations that you can run into console and ask SO question about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expression

```
0.5 < 0.6 < 0.7
```

is evaluated, like this

```
(0.5 < 0.6) < 0.7
```

Since the first part is `true`, it will be effectively

```
true < 0.7
```

Both the sides will be tried to be converted to a number and since `true` is `1` when converted to a number, the expression becomes

```
1 < 0.7
```

which is not correct. That is why `false` is returned.

---

Same way, in the second case,

```
1.5 < 1.6
```

is `true`, so it becomes `1` and the expression becomes

```
1 < 1.7
```

which is `true`.

---

You can check the behaviour of booleans as numbers, like this

```
console.log(+true);
// 1
console.log(+false);
// 0
console.log(Number(true));
// 1
console.log(Number(false));
// 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
0.5 < 0.6 // true
```

true became 1, because of the type changing to number

```
1 < 0.7 // false
```

the second one:

```
1.5 < 1.6 // true
```

true became 1, because of the type changing

```
1 < 1.7 // true
```

Answer (score 0):

The *associativity* of `<` is from left to right. And a boolean `true` has a numerical value of 1, and `false` has a value of 0.

Putting this together:

1. `0.5 < 0.6 < 0.7` is `(0.5 < 0.6) < 0.7` is `1 < 0.7` is `false`.
2. `1.5 < 1.6 < 1.7` is `(1.5 < 1.6) < 1.7` is `0 < 1.7` is `true`.

where the parentheses make the associativity clear.