# Why is 15 > 10 > 5 false?

Tags: javascript

The below javascript function outputs as `false`, why is it resulted in false ?

```
console.log(15 > 10 > 5);
```

Comment: Because `1 > 5 === false`.

Comment: by that statement you probably mean (15 < 10) && (10 > 5), and I believe by saying 15 > 10 > 5 what you actually do is (15 > 10) > 5, which gives you true > 5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange behaviour of javascript while chaining math comparison operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34674836/strange-behaviour-of-javascript-while-chaining-math-comparison-operators)

Comment: Better duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089284/why-does-0-5-3-return-true

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does (0 < 5 < 3) return true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089284/why-does-0-5-3-return-true)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because comparison operators takes two operands. So first, your code evaluates `15 > 10` which returns `true` and so then it does `true > 5` which obviously returns `false`

Comment: It's not that obvious at all why `true > 5` is false.

Comment: true is equal to 1, here you go

Comment: more exactly, `true > 5` makes no sense. However, `true` can be cast into a number, resulting in `1`. So `true > 5` will get cast into `1 > 5` which is `false`. Because of the above, `15 > 10 > -5` will return `true`.

Answer (score 2):

The [comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) take two operands and associates from left to right. This means the expression `15 > 10 > 5` is evaluated as `(15 > 10) > 5`.

`15 > 10` obviously evaluates to `true`.

`true > 5` is not that obvious how it is evaluated.

Fortunately, the [JavaScript documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Using_the_equality_operators) explains how the values are converted when they have different types:

> If one of the operands is Boolean, the Boolean operand is converted to `1` if it is true and `+0` if it is `false`.

This means `true > 5` is evaluated the same way as `1 > 5` and only now the result is clear: it is `false`.